# Error: NoSuchMethdError: La clase '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' no tiene no tiene captador de instancias 'fecha'

Tags: laravel, flutter

**Please help me with my code.
The code is written in flutter.**

I am trying to request appointments through APIREST in laravel using the `table_calendar` method in flutter. The problem is that when requesting  the day the appointment is cited, the following error appears:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCPlf.png)

I am using this method and put it in my FutureBuilder to compare it with my snapshot inside my `getData()` class (which is the one that receives the data from my API to send to call the database).

I want to see nothing but the appointment is marked on the date that the appointment has

```
class CitaList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CitaListState createState() => _CitaListState();
}

class _CitaListState extends State<CitaList> {
  List<dynamic> list;
  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/auth/cita");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  CalendarController _calendarController;
  UsuarioProvider usuarioProvider;
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _groupedEvents;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    // getData().th-en((value) => _fetchEvents());
  }

  _groupEvents(List<dynamic> events) {
    _groupedEvents = {};
    events.forEach((event) {
      event = event["Fecha"].split("/");
      final eventDay = int.parse(event[1]);
      DateTime date = DateTime.utc(eventDay);
      if (_groupedEvents[date] == null) _groupedEvents[date] = [];
      _groupedEvents[date].add(eventDay);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Citas'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final events = snapshot.data;
                _groupEvents(events);
                DateTime selectedDate = _calendarController.selectedDay;
                list = _groupedEvents[selectedDate] ?? [snapshot.data];
                return SizedBox(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TableCalendar(
                          events: _groupedEvents,
                          weekendDays: [6],
                          initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                          availableCalendarFormats: {
                            CalendarFormat.month: 'Meses',
                            CalendarFormat.week: 'Semanas'
                          },
                          locale: 'es_ES',
                          calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                            todayColor: Colors.orange,
                            selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            todayStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              ),
                              headerMargin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                              centerHeaderTitle: true,
                              formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                              formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                              leftChevronIcon:
                                  Icon(Icons.chevron_left, color: Colors.white),
                              rightChevronIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.chevron_right,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                          onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          builders: CalendarBuilders(
                            selectedDayBuilder: (context, day, events) =>
                                Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                              child: Text(
                                day.day.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                            todayDayBuilder: (context, day, events) =>
                                Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                              child: Text(
                                day.day.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          calendarController: _calendarController,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          DateFormat('M/dd/yyyy').format(selectedDate),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                child: ListTile(
                              title: Text('Titulo'),
                              subtitle: Text(list[i]['Fecha']),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            DetailCita(
                                              list: list,
                                              index: i,
                                            ))),
                              ),
                            )),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddCita(
                selectedDate: _calendarController.selectedDay,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help as I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in method `_groupEvents()`.

In your `getData()` method, you retrieve a JSON and parse/decode it. I assume that JSON you get from the API is a list. That's OK. But when you `json.decode` it, that returns a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. That's the standard return type. It isn't any weird type, it's the standard.

So, in your `FutureBuilder` `builder` property, you pass the retrieved snapshot (remember the type: `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`) to the `_groupEvents()` method, which then treats it as a `List` of some object type that you didn't specify. You have a type mismatch there.

In order to solve it: Inside your `events.forEach` loop, you have to cast each element of your `events` `List` to the correct object type before calling the `date` property on it.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific, sorry if I bother a lot

Comment: Please if you can leave an example it would be very helpful friend and sorry if I disturb you :)